# What is the proper way to catch and identify the HttpRequestException "The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.example.com'"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I want to be able to catch and identify the exceptions that belong to this specific type and then return a suitable error message. What is the proper way to do that in a catch block?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exception you need to catch is an `HttpRequestException` *specifically* with an `InnerException` that is a `WebException` and has a `Status` property with a value of `WebExceptionStatus.NameResolutionFailure`.

Fortunately, using C# 6.0 [exception filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/when#when-in-a-catch-statement), it's now easy to catch only an exception that fulfills these specific criteria:

```
var hc=new HttpClient();
try
{
    (await hc.GetStringAsync("https://www.googggle.com"));

}
catch(HttpRequestException ex) 
  when ((ex.InnerException as WebException)?.Status ==
           WebExceptionStatus.NameResolutionFailure)
{
    //yay. localization-proof
    Console.WriteLine("dns failed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, catch HttpRequestException in catch block

```
catch (HttpRequestException ex){}
```

Then if you need to closely identify the message, use ex.Message

```
if (ex.Message.StartsWith("The remote name could not be resolved:"))
{
     //do the rest
{
```

Comment: What about using the HResult instead of the exception message?

Comment: Fails in any non-English locale.

Comment: Not sure. Last time I wanted to use HResult it was giving me same HResult code for different exceptions, but I don't remember it well so you should try it